# Removing an element anywhere in URL by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First: I had a wrong strategy in the past to include useless/nonsense "seo_url=keyword" element in my url, and now I want to delete it anywhere in URL and rewrite my URLs without that element. (301 redirect)

Second: Sometimes an element or some elements are empty like "location=" or "location=&select=" I would remove these elements if they are empty anywhere in URL and rewrite my URLs without those elements. (301 redirect)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]



RewriteRule (.*)/$ /?countrySelect=$1
RewriteRule (.*)/+/(.*)-(.*)\.html$  search-products.php?countrySelect=$1&productselect=$2&submit=1
RewriteRule (.*)/tag/(.*) search-products.php?countrySelect=$1&keyword=$2
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)\.html$  search-products.php?productLocation=$2&countrySelect=$1&productselect=$3&submit=1
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)_(.*)\.html$  detail.php?name=$2&id=$3&detail=true&countrySelect=$1</IfModule>
```

Comment: Kindly show code you currently use .

Comment: Code added as requested

Comment: You use these links internally only (for publicly using pretty links). I do not understand why you want redirections on the corrected links ?

Comment: No, I use them publicly. Is anything in my code makes you think that way?

Comment: You rewrite from pretty links...

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1) to remove `seo_url=keyword` in a query string, use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to extract the parts before and after to keep

```
RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING}& (.*?)&seo_url=.*?&(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [R,L]
```

Ad 2) removing all empty elements from a query string works the same

```
RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING}& (.*?)&.*?=&(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [L]
```

You must add a query string to the target URL. If not, the query string will be appended unaltered.

Comment: Can you give an example what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I thought, you wanted to remove parts of the query string, don't you?

Comment: I want to remove all this: "seo_url=AnyKeywordHere" anywhere in URL

Comment: And also all empty elements/parameters

Comment: Removing `seo_url` is done with the first rule. Removing empty parameters is done with the second rule.

Comment: Should i replace this with anything: "QUERY_STRING" within your code?

Comment: "You must add a query string to the target URL. If not, the query string will be appended unaltered." what do you mean?

Comment: This is just an explanation for the `?` in the replacement of the rules.

Comment: When you add these two rules to your .htaccess, it should remove `seo_url` and ignore any empty parameters.

Comment: ah ok, thanks:) so I will add your code into my .htaccess without any change. If any problem will post here again

Comment: This code doesn't do anything: RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING}& (.*?)&.*?=&(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [L]

Comment: Also the first code doesn't redirect the links that already have seo_url=kw